# prove: $\sum_{r=0}^{ ∞}\frac{{{r+k}\choose{k}}}{(r+k)(r+k-1)}x^r=\frac{\left(k- 2\right)!}{k!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}}$

Tags: summation

prove:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{ ∞}\frac{{{r+k}\choose{k}}}{(r+k)(r+k-1)}x^r=\frac{\left(k-
2\right)!}{k!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}}$$
I tried to expand the sum such that:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{ ∞}\frac{{{r+k}\choose{k}}}{(r+k)(r+k-1)}x^r=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{r=0}^{ ∞}\frac{(r+k-
2)!}{r!}x^r$$
I think this sum can be seen as a geometric sum, but I cannot reach that.

here is a photo which maybe helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there!

By the binomial theorem, the RHS can be expanded as

$$ \frac{(k-2)!}{k!}\sum  {r+k-2  \choose k-2}   x^r,$$

It's an equality if the coefficients of $x^r$ are the same. Are they?

---

Here's the working

$$ \begin{array}{l l l } &=& \frac{(k-2)!}{k!}\sum  \frac{(r+k-2)!}{r!(k-2)!}   x^r \\
&= &\sum \frac{(r+k-2)!}{r!k!}  x^r \\
&=& \sum \frac{1}{(r+k)(r+k-1)} \times \frac{(r+k)!}{r!k!} x^r \\
&=& \sum \frac{1}{(r+k)(r+k-1)} {r+k \choose k } x^r  \\
&=& LHS \end{array} $$

Comment: yes you are right, but I still cannot get the finall result (the pic is not my work)

Comment: @Absurd All that was left was direct algebraic manipulation, which I have filled in. To me, the crux was in expanding the RHS as a power series via the (negative) binomial theorem.

Comment: but it's not like the finall answer

Comment: What is not like the final answer? Please elaborate.